# Responsive design in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive-design

I have build a site with responsive design. Everything is normal in Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Opera but Internet Explorer (version 10,11 also) shows tablet version in desktop PC. How can I force IE to use desktop version? Thank you in advance. Media queries are as following:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {}\\ for Tablet
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {} \\for Desktop PC
```

Comment: You need additional code for IE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869615(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Media queries are supported by IE 10 & 11. Could you share you css including those media queries ?

Comment: @Gerard, thanks for your effort. I tried the solution in your link but couldn't make it work. For the screen min-width:481px I should add  @-ms-viewport { width: 481px; }. Correct?

Comment: @j-printemps, media queries are as mentioned above in css. Do you need the whole css file? It is too long, how can I share it with you?

Comment: A sample might be enough. And also, could you tell us what your `<meta name="viewport"` is ?

Comment: @j-printemps, sample is in the question and '<meta name="viewport"' is as following, '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">'

Comment: @Nahid Mirzayev - yes, that's how I read it.

Comment: @Gerard, I made the changes mentioned in the link for every media query but it didn't work . Maybe I missed something..

Answer (score 1):

The following code loads mystyles.css in all browsers and loads complex.css only in Internet Explorer 8:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:600px)" href="mystyles.css" />

<!--[if (IE 8)]>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="complex.css" title="complex layout" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Should I use separate css file for Internet explorer? And this code must be in every page?

Comment: ITs add on header file

Comment: When I add this string to the header it doesn't shown properly on mobile devices